# filtering object so that only certain links are accepted

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter urls I grabbed using json but the code is not working

```
$.each(data.next, function(z,item){
  JSON.stringify(item.data.url);
  var url =item.data.url;
  if (url.substring(0,11)=='http://youtub'){

    var x = '<p>' + url + '</p>'; //this line and the one after that is just to put it in html
    $(x).appendTo("#text");
  }
});
```

Where did I make the error? I've never used stringify before so is that it?

Comment: that's true, i think the contents of item.data.url is already in a string but removing stringify() didn't help either

Comment: `JSON.stringify(item.data.url);`is nonsensical. It does nothing.

Comment: To clarify Thomas' statement, `JSON.Stringify(...)` is a function that returns a value, without assigning it `var strinifiedUrl = JSON.Stringify(...);` it won't do anything.

Comment: Is `data.next` an array or an object?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try actually using the variable return by `JSON.stringify`?

`var url = JSON.stringify(item.data.url);`

JSON.stringify doesn't modify the argument it is given, it return a converted format

See [documentation](http://veloper.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Also I am not sure why would anyone want to convert an easy to iterate over object into a string to build a filter. If anything a well build object would make filtering a bliss.

Comment: oops, sorry I was changing things trying to get my post to be in code format. the substring is indeed (0,13) and not (0,11)

Comment: Ah fair enough :) `indexOf` would be more efficient though as it will return only the position of the search string instead of doing any strip manipulation.

Comment: thank you! however is there another reason why my function is not filtering the url's correctly?